# jQuery Date Picker - do not pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ma starting with that i am obsiously blind, but i can't find a fail in my own code, please can someone find a minute and tell me what the hell i am doing wrong?

Code looks totaly OK for me but dispite this fact it's not working ofcourse.

Code looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="date-form">

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="date-picker-2" class="control-label">B</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="date-picker-2" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
                <label for="date-picker-2" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="date-picker-3" class="control-label">C</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="date-picker-3" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                </label>
                <input id="date-picker-3" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <hr />
</div>


<script>
$(".date-picker").datepicker();

$(".date-picker").on("change", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var val = $("label[for='" + id + "']").text();
    $("#msg").text(val + " changed");
});
</script>
```

And fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bbm035nx/1/

Unfortunately, here we have a problem, datepicker don't even popup, looks it didn't find jquery, but WHY or what happen? I have no clue. Please guys can somebody try to look at it?

Thank you all and again sorry for stupid question.

Comment: where are you including jquery-ui?

Comment: 3th line from start beck :)

Comment: thats only jquery not jquery-ui.. check this..http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: included , didn't help. :(

Comment: can you update the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the right panel. You forgot to include necessary libraries. Add them in order (jQuery > jQueryUI > Bootstrap) and it shoudl all work!

```
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript">
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbm035nx/2/